# Enabling Evolution Data server

Tags: evolution

I'm trying to work with Evolution once again. When I went to run the program, I get the following error message:

> Cannot start Evolution. Another Evoluiton instance may be
> unresponsive. System error: Error calling StartServiceByname for
> org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5 Unit
> evolution-source-registery.service is masked.

When I go to unmask the service, I get the following:

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask 
alsa-utils.service        rcS.service               x11-common.service
cryptdisks-early.service  saned.service             zfs-import.service
cryptdisks.service        sudo.service              zfs-load-key.service
hwclock.service           systemd-rfkill.service    
rc.service                systemd-rfkill.socket  

$ locate evolution-source-registry.service
/home/$USER/.config/systemd/user/evolution-source-registry.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/evolution-source-registry.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a few years ago I had mapped some disabling entries in

```
~/.config/systemd/user

lrwxrwxrwx 1 $$$ $$$ 9 Oct  6  2021 evolution-addressbook-factory.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 $$$ $$$ 9 Oct  6  2021 evolution-calendar-factory.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 $$$ $$$ 9 Oct  6  2021 evolution-source-registry.service -> /dev/null
lrwxrwxrwx 1 $$$ $$$ 9 Oct  6  2021 evolution-user-prompter.service -> /dev/null
```

Removing these entries allowed the service & Evolution to start normally.Thanks